# Instance of child class?

Tags: c#, .net, inheritance

How do I create an instance of a child class in C#?

```
public class Parent
{
    public virtual void test()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("this is parent");
    }
}

public class Child : Parent
{
    public override void test()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("this is from child");
    }
}

public static void main()
{
    //Which one is right below?

    Child ch = new Child();

    Parent pa = new Parent();

    ch = new Parent();

    pa = new Child();

    ch.test();

    pa.test();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your code you have four instantiations, that all mean slightly different things:

```
// create a new instance of child, treat it as an instance of type child
Child ch = new Child();

// create a new instance of parent, treat it as an instance of parent
Parent pa = new Parent();

// this will not compile; you cannot store a less specialized type in a variable
// declared as a more specialized type
Child ch = new Parent();

// create a new instance of child, but treat it as its base type, parent
Parent pa = new Child();
```

Which one (of those three that works) that is correct depends on what you want to achieve.

Note that the following two cases both print "this is from child":

```
Child ch = new Child();
ch.test();  

Parent pa = new Child();
pa.test();
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want an instance of `Child`, then `new Child()` is the right thing to do. However, as `Child` is a specialization of `Parent`, you may refer to it either through a `Child` or a `Parent` reference (`ch` and `pa` in your example).

So you have to decide if you want to access the instance as a `Child` or a `Parent`.

If you do

```
Child ch = new Child();
```

You have a reference, `ch` of the type `Child` pointing to an instance of `Child`.

If you do

```
Parent pa = new Child();
```

You have a reference, `pa` of the type `Parent` pointing to an instance of `Child`. I.e. you're taking advantage of the fact that inheritance builds a "is a" relationship between `Parent` and `Child`.

In other words the type `Child` is a specialization of `Parent`. Thus an instance of `Child` can be used anywhere an instance of `Parent` is needed.

Comment: i want to go for the instance of child ... which like out of above 4 i need to call?

Comment: If you call `new Child()`, you will get an instance of the type `Child`, but as I stated you can use either a reference of type `Child` or `Parent`. What are you trying to accomplish besides creating the instance?

Comment: what do you mean by reference type of parent or child? does reference type mean the left side part of "=" sign?

Comment: The type of `ch` is `Child` in you example and the type of `pa` is `Parent`. Either of these may reference an instance of the type `Child`. However, `ch` may not reference an instance of `Parent` as `Parent` cannot be considered a type of `Child`.

Answer (score 1):

this tends to be more fundamental, than you thought!
i recommend you reading a paper which explains you inheritance & polymorphism, eg [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173149.aspx), [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173152.aspx) or [codeproject](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/csharpintro01.aspx)

to me it's more about giving an explanation rather than a solution ...